# How can I get the name of fragment opened in current application from an Android service?

Tags: android, android-fragments, service

I'm writing a code for an application to be used in specific devices, installed from custom firmware not from google play. My client company wants to control the application their workers can use and also want to block the access to Configuration **except wifi and bluetooth settings**.

I did that and it is working properly, but not in tablets. In smartphones I can get the name of the current application and make my way to allow or block the access.

But, using a Tablet, I get only the main configuration (com.android.settings) but I can't know that fragment is opened.

If the user pull down the notification panel I can block the configuration access, and also allow the wifi settings. In this moment, with the wifi panel opened, he can navigate to any other configuration fragment and I can't control it.

My question is: can I get the name of the right fragment from the configurations activity, from a service?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get the Activity for API > 22 Only the packageName. Befor you can get The activity but not the fragment.